# XAML map control lib pushpin clustering on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, pushpin

I would like to do pushpin clustering on a map based on OpenStreetMap from C# VS2013 WPF.

I am using XAML map control lib (http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) and a push pin clustering lib (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Pushpin-Clustering-with-29f4b9f4).

In the push pin clustering lib, the defination of map is

```
Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Map
```

and I need to call the function

```
public GridBasedClusteredLayer(Map map, ClusterOptions options)
```

from GridBaseClusterdLayer.cs in the push pin clustering lib and

```
public void ZoomMap(System.Windows.Point origin, double zoomLevel)
```

from MapBase.cs in XMAL map control lib

so that I can do pushpin clustering when I zoom in and out.

But, in XAM map control lib, map defination is

```
xmlns:map="clr-namespace:MapControl;assembly=MapControl.WPF"
```

How can I solve the conflict so that I can do the pushpin clustering through XAML map control lib ? I do not want to use Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF in order to avoid the KEY.

**UPDATE**

May I add a parent class for Map in XAML map lib so that it can inheritate everything from the map definition in the pushpin clustering lib ?

In Map.WPF.cs of XAML map control lib,

```
public class Map : Mapbase, Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Map
```

Comment: You can't use the clustering code out of the box with XAML Map Control. You may however try to port it, as the APIs of XAML Map Control and Bing Maps are similar.

Comment: @Clemens, You mean I need to make a change to its definitions of map in the clustering code so that can be called from XAML map control ?

Comment: Exactly. You may however have to make some changes, as the APIs are of course not identical.

Comment: @Clemens, please see the UPDATE.

Comment: @Clemens, in the code of XAM map control lib, I have added a reference of pushpin cluster lib. Now, when I tried to make a new definition of  map in pushpin cluster lib so that it can be called from XAML map control lib, I have to add a reference of map definition from XAML map control lib, This will create a circle reference.

Comment: You would have to build the cluster lib with XAML Map Control **instead** of Bing Maps Control. This means to replace all occurences of the one by the other. This will certainly not work without some code changes. If you don't know how to do this, you should probably better not use it at all, and try to implement one of its algorithms on your own.